# Geopandas - read_file() function VERY slow through shared network. How to run application without reading in files through shared network

Tags: python, readfile, geopandas, shared-drive

My query is regarding the speed of implementing the `read_file()` or `from_file()` function in Geopandas.

The program I created needs to read in files of around 900,000 rows. When I specify the path within my own PC, it takes around 3 minutes.

Through the shared drive however, it takes 45+ minutes, not ideal for an application.

I know the VPN used makes the whole process incredibly slow, but how do companies use applications that access huge datasets and it not take an unreasonable amount of time. Is it specific servers?

My end goal is to make the application I made accessible to everyone that uses the shared drive without them having to download the files and alter the code to read them in.

Thanks for your help

Comment: 900,00 rows doesnt seem too bad -- why not host it on google drive or something?

Comment: I don't know how to read files larger than 100mb off google drive. Is there another software you'd recommend?

Comment: What about dropbox?